# Multiple errors in Android XML

Tags: java, android, xml

Learning Android and am having the following erros in my XML File:

- Error parsing XML: Junk after document element; and
- Attribute is missing the namespace prefix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android.password="true"
        android:hint="Type a Command" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bResults"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:text="Try Command" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:checked="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Look at your root element - you're closing it *before* all the other elements. Get rid of the `/` at the end of the opening tag.

Comment: you are closing your 1st linearlayout: change `/>` to `>`; and your edittext should be `android:password="true"`

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is in this section

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="25dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" />
```

you are closing the element with `/>`

Remove the `/`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="25dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

so that it isn't closed until the very end. You are closing the root element before the rest of the document.

and a litle change in your edittext:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <!-- change below the . to : -->
        android:password="true"
        android:hint="Type a Command" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the first editText, `android.password` should be `android:password`. That might be the source of your namespace error.

Further clarification: When you insert `xmlns:android` into the root element, you are declaring that all the children are accepting properties in the android "XML namespace (xmlns)". In example, `android.padding` is the property "padding" declared in the namespace "android".

The android linter (linter is a tool to check possible errors in code) checks if there is any property inside a default android XML element that doesn't belong to the "android" namespace, since probably every property from a default android node belongs to the android namespace.